# MY issue is all data is coming except the name when i begin with success url in stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The issue is when i add parameters in success url all data come but when i add name it gives error i have tried it and the conclusion i made is if i remove the spaces between letters then it work fine but i want to make it proper workable can you help me with it

```
 success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success/${product.email}/${product.quantity}/${product.amount}`,
```

[image: It works completely fine with data that have no space between them but doesnt work on data havong space]
All i need is to add name in it so this url look like this

```
 success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success/${product.name}/${product.email}/${product.quantity}/${product.amount}`,
```

But it gives this error if i add name

[image: Here is the error when i add product.name in it]

Comment: Hello. Did you debug it? I think that it is related that the URL is decoded. Check about URL encoding and solving for special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL must be encoded. If it is not done automatically, just wrap the URL inside this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

It replaces i.e. spaces with valid URL characters